# Styling elements individually in mapped array - styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have 4 buttons and each of them has its own correctness check as object prop - `isAnswerCorrect`.

I have also `isCorrect` state which i change whenever the button is correct or no.

What i want to achieve?

- when **correct** button is clicked, its border color changes to green and rest of the uncorrect buttons borders remain the same
- when **uncorrect** button is clicked all the uncorrect buttons change their border color to red and the correct button should change its border color to green

Currently what i have does not have much sense because uncorrect button changes all borders to red and same story with correct button which changes all borders to green. And thats because of that one and only `isCorrect` state.

How to make it properly with combination of styled components?

[image: Edit fancy-tdd-1gxx5c]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a helper function to set the value of `isCorrect`:

```
function isResponseCorrect(isAnswerCorrect) {
    if(isCorrect === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    if(isCorrect) {
      return isAnswerCorrect ? true : undefined;
    } else {
      return isAnswerCorrect ? true : false;
    }
  }

return (
    <Wrapper>
      {answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
        <AnswerButton
          isCorrect={isResponseCorrect(answerOption.isAnswerCorrect)}
          key={answerOption.id}
          onClick={
            () => handleAnswerCorrectness(answerOption.isAnswerCorrect) // TODO
          }
        >
          {answerOption.answerText}
        </AnswerButton>
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit cold-thunder-dec1ud]